# How to Show Columns in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning PHP and am trying to create some code outside of the tutorial I've been watching to understand it better and I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong with the code below. I have lots of other functions working just fine, just not this one. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

The result I get is Catchable fatal error: Object of class User could not be converted to string on line 20, which is `echo $user . "<br /><br />";`

Here is my index.php

```
<? 
$users = User::db_fields(); 
foreach($users as $user) {
echo $user . "<br /><br />";
}
?>
```

Here is my class User in user.php

```
<?php 
class User extends OtherStuff {

public static function db_fields() {
global $db;  
return static::find_by_sql("SHOW COLUMNS FROM my_table");
}
}
<?
```

Here is some of my OtherStuff class in other_stuff.php

```
class OtherStuff {

public static function find_by_sql($sql="") {
global $db;
$result_set = $db->query($sql);
$object_array = array();
while($row = $db->fetch_array($result_set)) {
   $object_array[] = static::instantiate($row);
} 
return $object_array;
}

public static function instantiate($record) {
$class_name = get_called_class();
$object = new $class_name;
foreach($record as $attribute => $value){
if($object->has_attribute($attribute)) {
$object->$attribute = $value;
}
} 
return $object;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You probably want `echo $user` instead of `echo $users`. `$users` is the array over which you are iterating.

Comment: I went ahead and made the fixes, please see my updated error.

Comment: PHP has some pretty good db interaction functions built into it (in both PDO and mysqli). Until you get more comfortable with those and the language in general, I suggest that you don't go making things unnecessarily complicated by writing your own wrappers for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well....Your calling db_fileds() statically.

```
User::db_fields();
```

So it needs to be a static function..

```
public static function db_fields() {
```

**EDIT**

You could do this as a workaround...

Change your query

```
return static::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 1");
```

Then do this...

```
$fields = User::db_fields(); 
 foreach($fields as $key=>$value ) {
      echo $key; // This will give the field name
 }
```

**EDIT 2**

To preserve the column names linked to the fields.

Although this is likely wrong, because now its instantiating multiple times, and what happens in a case where an object doesnt find an attribute and doesn't get written, then you miss a column.

But the idea is there...

```
while($row = $db->fetch_array($result_set)) {

    foreach($row as $k=>$v){
       $object_array[$k] = static::instantiate($row);
    }  

}
```

Comment: Then the error is deeper....have you succesfully retrieved any db rows with the setup you have?  like whats going on in static::instantiate($row)

Comment: Yes, I can retrieve anything from the db. I just can't seem to get it to give me the table columns. Added that function above to my code.

Comment: Check my edit.  SHOW COLUMNS creates a temporary table, so it might be screwing up behind the scenes for you.  To make it work with the setup you have, try what I just posted

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. What it shows me now is the numbers 0 - 30 (which is home many items I have in my DB) because I removed the LIMIT.  If I put in SHOW COLUMNS then I get the number 0 - 10 (number of columns I have) The only problem is, how can I get the Column names.

Comment: Hmm...its because youre doing some funky stuff in instantiate($row), and youre returning an array of objects, not the original ROW query array....so you have actually lost the column names.  You need to store them as the key, in the $object_array[] or something along those lines

Answer (score 0):

You made a silly:

`echo $users . "<br /><br />";` should have `$user` as the echo param

```
<? 
$users = User::db_fields(); 
foreach($users as $user) {
echo $user . "<br /><br />";
?>
```

You were printing the original array every time

**Edit:**

The new error is a reflection of the fact that your `User` class does not explicitly define a way for objects of the class to be converted to strings. If you want to do a quick n dirty output, you can `var_dump()` your objects, but eventually you'll want to override the `__toString()` method. Check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) out.

You can also simply make a function in the `User` class that returns the string you want and just call it with `$user->StringifyUser()`. The (main) difference between this approach is that PHP will not implicitly convert your `User` class objects to strings when used in your originally context.

**Edit 2:**

I would also check out the other answers, especially that of KyleK who addresses several key points that I did not touch on.

Comment: I went ahead and made the fixes, please see my updated error.

Answer (score 0):

Well the array you're iterating over is $users, and the values you're getting from $users are going into $user.

But you're echoing $users (the Array). If the values in your $users array are all strings (or some other scalar value) you should be fine by changing your code to:

```
<? 
$users = User::db_fields(); 
foreach($users as $user) {
  echo $user . "<br /><br />";
}
?>
```

(I also added in your missing brace at the end)

Comment: I went ahead and made the fixes, please see my updated error.